# How to show the last selected dropdown value after insert PHP values in Mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a plenty of list of writers and publishers which are to be inserted in mysql through PHP, but every time I have to select between **`"Add Writer"`** and **`"Add Publisher"`** manually after inserting every **writer/publisher** details.

I want the selected values doesn't get changed automatically on inserting values in Mysql, (until it changed by user) i.e., selected option remains same (chosen by user) even after inserting the values, until changed by user.

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
include "dbConfig.php"; 

/*Adding Writer*/
if(isset($_POST['addwrt']))
{
    $writerid=$_POST['writerid'];
    $wname=$_POST['wname'];
    $wcity=$_POST['wcity'];


    $resultw=mysqli_query($db,"insert into wdetails(writerid,wname,wdesg,salutation,wcity)values('$writerid','$wname','$wdesg','$salut','$wcity')");
    }



/*Adding Publisher*/
else if(isset($_POST['addpubl']))
{
    $publisherid=$_POST['publisherid'];
    $pname=$_POST['pname'];
    $pcity=$_POST['pcity'];



    $resultp=mysqli_query($db,"insert into pdetails(publisherid,pname,pdesg,pcity)values('$publisherid','$pname','$pdesg','$pcity')");
    }

?>
<body>
<select id="stf">
<option value="cf" selected="selected" />Select the Field
<option value="addwriter" />Add Writer
<option value="addpublisher" />Add Publisher
</select>

<form method="post" name="libraryAdd">
<div id="addwriter" style="display:none">
<table>

<tr>
<td>Writer ID<span style="color:red"><b>*</b></span></td>
<td>W&nbsp;<input type='text' name="writerid"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Writer Name<span style="color:red"><b>*</b></span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="wname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Writer City<span style="color:red"><b>*</b></span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="wcity" /></td>
<td><input name="addwrt" type="submit" value="ADD Data"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

<div id="addpublisher" style="display:none">
<table>

<tr>
<td>Publisher ID<span style="color:red"><b>*</b></span></td>
<td>P&nbsp;<input type='text' name="publisherid"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Publisher Name<span style="color:red"><b>*</b></span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Publisher City<span style="color:red"><b>*</b></span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pcity" /></td>
<td><input name="addpubl" type="submit" value="ADD Data"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

**`.js`** file linked to the **`index.php`**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stf').change(function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        if(value === "addwriter"){
       $("#addwriter").show('slow');
       $("#addpublisher").hide('slow');
       }
       else if(value === "addpublisher"){
       $("#addpublisher").show('slow');
       $("#addwriter").hide('slow');
       }
        else {
         $("#addwriter").hide('slow');
         $("#addpublisher").hide('slow');
     }
    });
 });
```

**`dbConfig.php`**

```
<?php
//Database credentials
$dbHost     = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName     = 'library';

//Connect and select the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is that in your select you have:

```
<option value="cf" selected="selected" />Select the Field
```

which means that the select will always start with "Select the Field" selected.

If you want the last selected option to remain selected after form submission, you should change the select code to:

```
<option value="cf" <?php if (!isset($_POST['addwrt']) && !isset($_POST['addpubl'])) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Select the Field
<option value="addwriter" <?php if (isset($_POST['addwrt'])) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Add Writer
<option value="addpublisher" <?php if (isset($_POST['addpubl'])) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Add Publisher
```

You will also need to make the following changes to ensure the appropriate input boxes appear. Change

```
<div id="addwriter" style="display:none">
<div id="addpublisher" style="display:none">
```

to:

```
<div id="addwriter" <?php if (!isset($_POST['addwrt'])) echo 'style="display:none"'; ?> >
<div id="addpublisher" <?php if (!isset($_POST['addpubl'])) echo 'style="display:none"'; ?> >
```

Comment: Thanks but after inserting first time, the input box is not displaying again for inserting second writer details. Where is the issue? Kindly help...